# If Equal to this or this

Tags: jquery

I'm sure this is a simple answer, I just can't figure it out!

I need to check whether a variable is equal to multiple things:

```
if ((dls == '10:0') && (dls == '10:3') && (dls == '11:0') && (dls == '11:3')){
    stamp = 'PM';
};
```

Test Page: http://pmf.v5.cloudsvr.com.au/-artists/axle

You'll see the alert firing, and DLS == 11:3 in the alert, but stamp still equals AM not PM.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT: I was using the wrong operators! **

```
if ((dls == '10:0') || (dls == '10:3') || (dls == '11:0') || (dls == '11:3')){
        stamp = 'PM';
};
```

Comment: My favorite part is that the question is titled "equal to this OR this" but you used the AND operator. :D

Comment: I didn't know it even existed using || :( now I do though! lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `||` operator, `Your condition will not be true as using &&` The if statement with && requires all the *given conditions to be true which means dls should have 10:0, 10:3, 11:0 and 11:3 values in variable at a time but variable can have one of those at a time*.

Change

```
if ((dls == '10:0') && (dls == '10:3') && (dls == '11:0') && (dls == '11:3')){
    stamp = 'PM';
};
```

To

```
if ((dls == '10:0') || (dls == '10:3') || (dls == '11:0') || (dls == '11:3')){
    stamp = 'PM';
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `||` instead of `&&`

```
if ((dls == '10:0') || (dls == '10:3') || (dls == '11:0') || (dls == '11:3')){
    stamp = 'PM';
};
```

`dls` cannot be all those value.. it is going to be either of those values.. so you need to use `||` (or operator) instead of `&&` (and operator)

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have meant to use || (OR) instead of &&  (AND):

```
if ((dls == '10:0') || (dls == '10:3') || (dls == '11:0') || (dls == '11:3')){
    stamp = 'PM';
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you are using the wrong operator .. Try using `||` instead of `&&`

You can try this approach too

```
var arr = ['10:0' , '10:3' , '11:0' , '11:3']
var dls = '10:1';

if ( arr.indexOf(dls) != -1){
    stamp = 'PM';
}
else{
   alert('Not PM')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/MS8V8/1/

```
val = $.grep(["10:0", "10:3", "11:0", "11:3"], function(n){ if(n === dls) return n; });
if(val[0] === dls) stamp = "PM";

alert(stamp);
```

Answer (score -1):

Shorter version:

```
if (dls == ('10:0'||'10:3'||'11:0'||'11:3')){
    stamp = 'PM';
};
```